Condition for $f(z-z_{0})=f(z_{0}-z)$ in Laurent's expansion of a function $f$,where $z_0$ is a singularity of $f$.
I was given a result in the class,which I want to prove.The result is,

"Let $z=z_0$ is the only singularity of $f$ within and on,a simple closed curve $\gamma$ and $f(z-z_{0})=f(z_{0}-z)$.Then integral of $f(z)$ along the simple closed curve $\gamma$ is zero."

I tried to prove it by Laurent's expansion,in a hope that the residue of $f$ will be zero at $z_0$ but this expansion forced me to think that this condition is only valid when $z_0=0$.Kindly help me.


Hint: Integral over $\gamma$ equals integral over a small circle around $z_0$.

@geetha290krm Thank you for your reply mam.Mam,how can I use the given condition?

Integral of an odd function from $-\pi$ to $+\pi$ is $0$.

@geetha290krm Mam, if $f(z-z_{0})=f(z_{0}-z)$ ,then will it imply that $f$ is an even function?

@geetha290krm does this condition $f(z-z_{0})=f(z_{0}-z)$ not imply that $z_{0}=0$,where $z_0$ is a singularity of $f$.

You have
$$
\oint_\gamma f(z) \,\mathrm{d}z = 2\pi i\operatorname{Res}(f,z_0),
$$
by the residue formula, but the said residue is equal to zero, because the condition $f(z-z_0) = f(z_0-z)$ implies that the Laurent series of $f$ around its singularity contain only even powers.

Please see the attached image and kindly guide me how can I prove that $b_{i}'s$ are zero for all odd $i$.

Thank you for your reply.
